# Jira Xray missing Results Output

Tags: junit, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am currently exporting my jUnit test results to Xray via REST API V2.
All is fine and as expected, except when a test fails there is no error logged, the Output field is blank:
[image: Missing output]

I am importing the jUnit xml file after running Android tests. I have not modified it. It's a typical jUnit xml file.
Is there an additional step required in order to get the error message to display in the execution details ticket?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update - I've since figure out that if I manually add a type attribute to the failure this now works. E.g. `<failure type="my.failure.type">Sample error message</failure>`
But I manually added this. Unsure how to get this attribute included automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JUnit XML is a "de facto standard" but there is no accurate specification for it. Different frameworks may produce slightly different XML reports.
In Xray for Jira server/DC, how Xray processes the JUnit XMl report is described, at least to a certain point, [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Taking+advantage+of+JUnit+XML+reports).
There may be some limitations though. One of them is related to the "message" attribute on the  element; as of v4.x, is is not processed as detailed [here](https://jira.xpand-it.com/browse/XRAY-4637).
On the concrete problem you reported, that seems to be related to the presence of  "type" attribute, that is currently required.
I see two ways moving forward:

- add the "type" on the  element; this may require you to implement it on the test runner/framework that generates it. This will be a more straighforward approach; if you're using an open-source testing framework, you can try to support it or ask the open-source community of that project to provide support for it
- or handle it on Xray side.. I would recommend you to reach [Xray team](https://jira.xpand-it.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) and open a support ticket, as this may be an improvement that needs to be supported (it will need to be analyzed).